# For every consecutive number

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list containing data such as `[2, 3, 9, 10, 16, 17, 23, 24, 99, 112, 113, 114, 299]` and what I would is that, for every set of consecutive numbers, construct a dictionary with the key representing the set of consecutive numbers starting from 1, and the value the consecutive numbers.

The expected output should look like this:

```
{1: [2, 3], 2: [9, 10], 3: [16, 17], 4: [23, 24], 5: [99], 6: [112, 113, 114], 7: [299]}
```

Is there an efficient way of doing this?

Comment: are they always going to be in pair, or is it possible to have non-consecutive numbers in the list too?

Comment: Katsu, I've improved your sample input to hopefully clarify what your text explained. Please check if my reading of your text was correct.

Comment: @paxdiablo I don't think it is a good idea to change the question with expected result on behalf of OP. For example, in this case OP can say that all his numbers are in pairs, and in that case answer could be fetched just by slicing (or `zip`). Your solution will be an overkill for it

Comment: @Anonymous: I I only changed the *data* used for the example, and then only because the text ("for every set of consecutive numbers, construct a dictionary with the key representing the set of consecutive numbers starting from 1, and the value the consecutive numbers") made it clear what was expected (groups of consecutive numbers, not pairs). Nothing in the text itself was changed. This was done because there were several answers that assumed pairs, so it needed some clarity. I also requested OP to check my changes matched the requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will do what you want:

```py
def splitCons(lst):
    retlst = {}

    # Keep empty dict unless there are items.

    if len(lst) > 0:
        # Populate first keyed item with first element.

        key = 1
        retlst = {key:[lst[0]]}

        # Process other elements.

        for num in lst[1:]:
            # Consecutive to previous? Add to existing. Otherwise, add to new.

            if num == retlst[key][-1] + 1:
                retlst[key].append(num)
            else:
                key += 1
                retlst[key] = [num]

    return retlst

print(splitCons([2, 3, 9, 10, 16, 17, 23, 24, 99, 112, 113, 114, 299]))
```

It simply creates the dictionary and either adds elements to the current last key (if consecutive) or starts a new key (if not).

Output for the test data in the given script (slightly modified to show correct operation where sets are not always pairs), and formatted for readability:

```py
{
    1: [2, 3],
    2: [9, 10],
    3: [16, 17],
    4: [23, 24],
    5: [99],
    6: [112, 113, 114],
    7: [299]
}
```

Comment: thank you for yr clear answer, very helpfull

Answer (score 0):

The following will generate your desired output:

```
def cons(lst):
    i, res = 0, {}
    for x in lst:
        if i not in res or res[i][-1] != x-1:
             i += 1
             res[i] = []
        res[i].append(x)
    return res

cons([2, 3, 9, 10, 16, 17, 23, 24])
# {1: [2, 3], 2: [9, 10], 3: [16, 17], 4: [23, 24]}
```

Comment: Assumes pairs, which is not the case according to the question text (though OP probably should have chosen better test data).

Comment: Yeah, just noticed. Fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
source = [2, 3, 9, 10, 16, 17, 23, 24]
result = dict()
temp_list = list()
internal_counter = 1

for index, item in enumerate(source):
    temp_list.append(item)
    if (index + 1) % 2 == 0:
        result.setdefault(internal_counter, []).extend(temp_list)
        temp_list = list()
        internal_counter += 1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
l = [2, 3, 9, 10, 16, 17, 23, 24]
print({i: c for i, c in enumerate(zip(l[::2], l[1::2]), 1)})
```

Perhaps a bit complex but uses dictionary and list comprehension and zip function.